# How to call only a certain number of arrays in an external api with express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, axios

I am currently learning about external API's using axios, express, and node. This is the code I am using to call the API:

```
app.get("/externalapi", (req, res) => {
 ;

  let apiURL = 'https://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json';
    axios.get(apiURL)
        .then(response => {
            
            res.status(200).json(response.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).json({ message: err });
        });
});
```

This code would successfully return ALL the data in that API when I use a GET request from Postman. However, I would only like to call the first 10 arrays of that API. an example data of the API is:

```
 [
  {
            "id": 495,
            "brand": "maybelline",
            "name": "Maybelline Face Studio Master Hi-Light Light Booster Bronzer",
            "price": "14.99",
            "price_sign": null,
            "currency": null,
            "image_link": "https://d3t32hsnjxo7q6.cloudfront.net/i/991799d3e70b8856686979f8ff6dcfe0_ra,w158,h184_pa,w158,h184.png",
            "product_link": "https://well.ca/products/maybelline-face-studio-master_88837.html",
            "website_link": "https://well.ca",
            "description": "Maybelline Face Studio Master Hi-Light Light Boosting bronzer formula has an expert \nbalance of shade + shimmer illuminator for natural glow. Skin goes \nsoft-lit with zero glitz.\n\n\t\tFor Best Results: Brush over all shades in palette and gently sweep over \ncheekbones, brow bones, and temples, or anywhere light naturally touches\n the face.\n\n\t\t\n\t\n\n                    ",
            "rating": 5,
            "category": null,
            "product_type": "bronzer",
            "tag_list": [],
            "created_at": "2016-10-01T18:36:15.012Z",
            "updated_at": "2017-12-23T21:08:50.624Z",
            "product_api_url": "https://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products/495.json",
            "api_featured_image": "//s3.amazonaws.com/donovanbailey/products/api_featured_images/000/000/495/original/open-uri20171223-4-9hrto4?1514063330",
            "product_colors": []
        }

]
```

I know you have to use a for loop to call only a certain number of arrays. However, I have almost no idea how to go about that and I would love to learn how to do it. May I please ask of some assistance. I know it's a simple question but I am a beginner trying to learn how to call and manipulate data from external API's

Comment: The only arrays I see are empty. What do you mean?

Comment: The code would  would fetch arrays of information about a certain makeup. The one I provided is only one of the hundreds of arrays of information in the external api. I want to create a loop to where it only gives me 10 of the hundreds of arrays (which contains information about makeup) from the external API.

Comment: Are you looking to call the API, *then* perform the filtering of the returned Objects in your code? Or are you asking how you would limit the number of results returned to your code by the API response to begin with?

Comment: `const first10 = response.data.slice(0, 10);`.

Comment: @esqew Im asking how would I limit the number of results returned to my code by the API. On the api call I sent above that shows the id and brand and name, that whole block is an example of one of the results. However, my api fetch code would return hundreds of those blocks. I only want 10 of those returned to me

Comment: If that’s the case, have you consulted your API of choice’s documentation to see if they support such a mechanism to limit the amount of results? If not, there isn’t any practical way to do so, and it’s not clear how you might arrive at a conclusion otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The `.slice()` method should help

```
res.status(200).json(responde.data.slice(0, 10));
```

Comment: Huh? Where exactly are you seeing `res` in the OP’s circumstance? Can you elaborate as to how you reached the conclusion that the OP is even in control of the backend in this scenario?